# Click the link with Selenium on C #

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I used the following code to be able to click on the job link on the C # code but it couldn't find it.

C#:

```
   1. driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Jobs List")).Click();
   2. driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*='jobs']")).Click();
   3. driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[@href='/jobs'])")).Click();
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/jobs" class="pr-0 pl-1 left-menu-item v-list-item v-list-item--link theme--light" tabindex="0">
    <div class="v-list-item__icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-credit-card-multiple theme--light white--text"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="v-list-item__title">Jobs List</div>
</a>
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator seems correct. If you are encountering "No Such Element Exception", try to add implicit wait `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);`